# How far a sphere will move if we stick smaller sphere at different positions

Tags: gravity, friction, rotational-kinematics, rotation

There is a big sphere of mass M and radius R, and a small sphere with mass m and radius r. Now smaller sphere is stuck at a certain height and angle $\theta$.
The ball would roll to some distance. I wanted to calculate to what distance it will move.

I thought to solve this thinking like a see-saw and at one side a ball is kept of mass m it will make the rotation.

I thought of 
$$(PE+KE+RE)_{init}=(PE+KE+RE)_{finally}$$
$$mgh + 0 + 0 = 0 + (1/2)(M+m)v^2 + (1/2)I(v/r)^2$$
$$mgh = (1/2)(M+m)*v^2 + (1/2)I(v/r)^2$$
$$I = (2/5)MR^2 + [ (2/5)mr^2 +m(R-r)^2 ]$$
$$v = \sqrt{\frac{2mgh}{M + 2.4m + mR(R-2r) + 0.4M(R/r)^2}}$$

```
          assuming friction
```

$$f = uN = u(m+M)g$$
$$f=(m+M)a   =>  a=ug$$

But how to calculate until what distance it will go. Also practically before stopping it will not stop general point but more of approximation how can we calc that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final position will be where the added mass is at its lowest point. So the distance is simply the arc length between the lowest point of the ball at the start and the attachment point of the mass.

1. When you attach the small mass, the ball will start rolling. The mass will be lowered and the potential energy of the mass will be turned into kinectic energy of the ball+mass.
2. It will pick up momentum and "overshoot" the "mass down" point and keep rolling.
3. At this point the mass will go up again and slow down the ball. Due to conservation of energy the mass will be not exceed the initial height.
4. It will keep rolling back and forth until all the initial potential energy of the mass has been turned into heat through friction
5. Final resting point will be the one with the lowest center of gravity, i.e. "mass down"

Comment: Thank You: So final point will be d=arclength=theta*R ,